# How to get Angular SignalR hub connection to Azure Typescript Function with version 4.0 programming model

Tags: angular, typescript, azure, azure-functions, azure-signalr

I’m having an issue getting my Angular 12 front end connected to my Azure SignalR and Azure Functions (server less Typescript) backend. I have `negotiate()` firing but erroring back in the client, and haven’t gotten upstream triggering (posts) working.

I have a two part question:

1. What is wrong with my Azure Function version 4 programming model binding syntax?
2. Given my `negotiate()` function returns hard coded values (see 'The Preliminary Stuff - Client Side' and `signalRConnectionInfo` below) how do I solve the angular **'Error: None of the transports supported by the client are supported by the server.'** when connecting?

**TLDR: The `negotiate()` function firing works with no additional input bindings, but returns an error to the Angular call to `this.hubConnection.start().then().catch()` method, e.g.: '*Error: None of the transports supported by the client are supported by the server.*'.**

**When I do try to add the input bindings formatted as described below the Function crashes returning `status 500` before it starts execution.**

The following is the walkthrough of what I found, and how I got to the binding I’m using at present.  I outline all of this because I have not seen anywhere how to do this.  In fact, according to Microsoft,  they don’t even have examples on how to do this yet: **“Example binding for Node.js model v4 not yet available.”**.

[image]

To find that disclosure by Microsoft, select Programming Model version 4 (it’s a tab you can select halfway down the page).
See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/add-bindings-existing-function?tabs=python-v2%2Cisolated-process%2Cnode-v4&pivots=programming-language-typescript

*My stack: Serverless Azure Function (Typescript) with version 4.0 programming model, Azure SignalR Free-tier Serverless.  Angular 12 front end severed on Azure Static Web App (with custom domain).*

**The Preliminary Stuff - Client Side**

My angular app is calling my Azure Function root level (e.g.: `https://<FUNCTION-URL>/api/`) in the construction of the HubConnectionBuilder() (see `@microsoft/signalr` doco).  I’m passing the hard coded `options` of `endpoint` and `accessKey` (and `authType: ‘azure.msi;Version=1.0;’`) in the same way as shown in this example:
See https://medium.com/medialesson/serverless-real-time-messaging-with-azure-functions-and-azure-signalr-service-c70e781ff3c3

In the above article (Step 3), note the format of the `SignalRConnectionInfo` object being passed as the `options` parameter.  As mentioned above, I’ve tried it with both the `accessKey` syntax and my own guess at using an `authType` parameter to try and get Server Managed Identity working.
NOTE: Yes I intend to have a secure Azure Function where I can request this prior to constructing the HubConnectionBuilder object, but for now that is unnecessary detail, and does not work being the `negotiate()` input binding issue.

This gives me something in my Angular code that looks like this (in class constructor):

```
    const options: any = {
        endpoint: this.config?.signalRHostName,
        authType: 'azure.msi;Version=1.0;',
        // accessKey: 'ZYp9h52IfYouCanReadThisYouAreTooClosenweLQDoXMg='
    };

    let functionAppUrl = this.config?.functionHostName + '/api/';

    this.hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
    .configureLogging(LogLevel.Debug)
    .withUrl(functionAppUrl, options)
    .build();

    this.hubConnection
    .start()
    .then(() => {
        console.log('************* SignalR connection started');
        this.sendHi();
    })
    .catch((err: any) => {
        console.log('************* Error while starting SignalR connection', err)
    });
```

**The Preliminary Stuff - Server Side**

The server side needs an Azure Function called `negotiate()` that has the extra binding of `signalRConnectionInfo`  and returns the connection string. This second binding being the topic of the part 1) question.  To address the question I looked for examples of version 4.0 programming model binding to understand how binding works and how we might game this out, in the absence of quality tutorials and examples. The following are the articles I’ve found that describe how they *might* bind.

1. I started with version 3 examples of the `negotiate()` function’s bindings (these examples are the old style per the other ‘answer’ and I add the here for prosperity of the full narrative).  The example shows we need a `signalRConnectionInfo` input binding as mentioned above and the values I’m going to try and replicate using version 4 programming model.
   See https://medium.com/holisticon-consultants/serverless-real-time-application-with-azure-signalr-5300e46a8b4b
2. We note the version 4 programming model of Azure Functions is different, and this article touches on how you might expect to pass those bindings now that we don’t have a `functions.json` file to play with.  Particularly note section "Extra inputs and outputs“ and also not the `import` statement bringing in `input` and `output`.  Also note the example shows `output.storageBlob`. When I try this, Visual Studio Code provides autocomplete for storageBlob, but if I try `output.signalr` there is nothing!  Make sure you read the part “Generic inputs and outputs
   ” also (because I thought this might be needed per the next point).
   See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-node?tabs=typescript%2Cwindows%2Cazure-cli&pivots=nodejs-model-v4#supported-versions
3. This link shows the Azure Functions version 4 programming model extensions.  As you can see, SignalR is included (as is StorageBlob) and I would assume available Visual Studio Code autocomplete feature.  However, SignalR is NOT found, so I might be (probably am) wrong on this.  I’m open to input on why my assumption that SignalR should autocomplete is wrong.
   See https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-extension-bundles/blob/v4.x/src/Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle/extensions.json
4. The following article seems to imply that SignalR is compatible with the new version 4 binding extensibility model.
   See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/azure/azure-functions/functions-versions?tabs=isolated-process%2Cv4&pivots=programming-language-typescript

**The Hackathon**

Given the inputs and outputs for the additional bindings per point number 2) above, I was hoping I could bind configuration input data for the `negotiate()` function like this:

```
import { app, input, output, HttpResponseInit, InvocationContext } from '@azure/functions';
import { Log, IRequest, AuthUtils, AzureADHelper } from '@wetware/viewdu-fxa';

export async function negotiate(request: IRequest, context: InvocationContext): Promise<HttpResponseInit> {
    await Log.setup(context);
    Log.debug(`>>> Http function processed request for url "${request.url}"`);
    context.log('************* signalR context.extraInputs', context.extraInputs);

    const connection = {
        hubName: 'deafult',
        // "connectionStringSetting": "Endpoint=https://sgr-xxxxx.service.signalr.net;AccessKey=ZYp9h52IfYouCanReadThisYouAreTooClosenweLQDoXMg=;Version=1.0;"
        connectionStringSetting: 'Endpoint=https://sgr-xxxxx.service.signalr.net;AuthType=azure.msi;Version=1.0;'
    };

    return {
        status: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify(connection, null, 2)
    };
};

const signalRInput = input.generic({
    type: 'signalRConnectionInfo',
    name: 'connectionInfo',
    hubName: 'default',
    // "connectionStringSetting": "AzureSignalRConnectionString",
    // "connectionStringSetting": "Endpoint=https://sgr-xxxxx.service.signalr.net;AccessKey=ZYp9h52IfYouCanReadThisYouAreTooClosenweLQDoXMg=;Version=1.0;"
    connectionStringSetting: 'Endpoint=https://sgr-xxxxx.service.signalr.net;AuthType=azure.msi;Version=1.0;'
})

app.http('negotiate', {
    methods: ['POST', 'GET'],
    authLevel: 'anonymous',
    handler: negotiate,
    extraInputs: [signalRInput]
});
```

To try and have a signalR trigger an upstream Azure Function, I was hoping I could trigger bind the Azure Function like this:
See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-signalr-service-trigger?tabs=isolated-process&pivots=programming-language-javascript

```
import { app, input, output, HttpResponseInit, InvocationContext } from '@azure/functions';
import { Log, IRequest, AuthUtils, AzureADHelper } from '@wetware/viewdu-fxa';

export async function signalRTrigger(request: IRequest, context: InvocationContext): Promise<HttpResponseInit> {
    await Log.setup(context);
    Log.debug(`>>> Http function processed request for url "${request.url}"`);
    context.log('************* signalR context.extraInputs', context.extraInputs);

    const connection = {
        hubName: 'default',    
        // connectionStringSetting: 'Endpoint=https://sgr-xxxxx.service.signalr.net;AccessKey=ZYp9h52IfYouCanReadThisYouAreTooClosenweLQDoXMg=;Version=1.0;',
        connectionStringSetting: 'Endpoint=https://sgr-xxxxx.service.signalr.net;AuthType=azure.msi;Version=1.0;'
    };

    return {
        status: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify(connection, null, 2)
    };

};

// This should provide the signalR upstream target to trigge
const signalrInput = input.generic({
    type: 'signalRTrigger',
    name: 'invocation',
    hubName: 'default',
    category: 'messages',
    event: 'SendMessage',
    parameterNames: [
       'message'
    ]
});

/* 
"type": "signalRTrigger",
"name": "invocation",
"hubName": "SignalRTest",
"category": "messages",
"event": "SendMessage",
"parameterNames": [
    "message"
],
"direction": "in"
 */

app.http('signalr-trigger', {
    methods: ['POST', 'GET'],
    authLevel: 'anonymous',
    handler: signalRTrigger,
    extraInputs: [signalrInput]
});
```

Has anyone had success using the Azure Function version 4.0 model with binding specifically to Azure SignalR (server-less)? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I've solved part 1 and am sharing how I got v4 Programming Model binding working using generics.  I'll add to this when I solve for the **'Error: None of the transports supported by the client are supported by the server.'** error.

NOTE: Even though these bindings work and the values are available within the Function, the `output` binding appears to be sending a `POST` request to SignalR with a Bearer Token.  The `input` appears to work (I'm not getting failed authentication errors in my Angular code) when I access `options` in the `negotiate()` function:

`context.log('************* signalR context', context.options.extraInputs);`

But this Microsoft site states that `options` from `http.output()` doesn't work and not sure what that means - per above the output binding itself seems to work.
See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook-output?tabs=isolated-process%2Cnodejs-v4&pivots=programming-language-typescript

[image]

If anyone can help solve that part 2 question I'm happy to still give you the points!

Binding for the signalRTrigger Azure Function:

```
/* 

V3 SYNTAX BEING CONVERTED TO V4 MODEL

"type": "signalRTrigger",
"name": "invocation",
"hubName": "SignalRTest",
"category": "messages",
"event": "SendMessage",
"parameterNames": [
    "message"
],
"direction": "in"
 */
```

The new code:

```
import { app, HttpRequest, output, trigger, HttpResponseInit, InvocationContext } from '@azure/functions';

export async function signalRTrigger(request: HttpRequest, context: InvocationContext): Promise<HttpResponseInit> {

    // **** - Add your signalR Azure Function code here

};

// This should provide the signalR upstream target to trigge
const signalTriggerConfig = trigger.generic({
    type: 'signalRTrigger',
    name: 'invocation',
    hubName: 'default',
    category: 'messages',
    event: 'SendMessage',
    parameterNames: [
       'message'
    ]
});


app.generic('signalr-trigger', {
    trigger: signalTriggerConfig,
    return: output.generic({
        type: 'http'
    }),
    handler: signalRTrigger
});
```

For the `input` and `output` binding make sure you have your `local.settings.json` and/or Azure Function configurations present or you'll get a 500 response error.

For the `input` binding:

```
/* 

V3 SYNTAX BEING CONVERTED TO V4 MODEL

{
  "type": "signalRConnectionInfo",
  "name": "connectionInfo",
  "hubName": "default",
  "connectionStringSetting": "AzureSignalRConnectionString",
  "direction": "in"
}
 */
```

I'm using the following code:

```
import { app, HttpRequest, input, HttpResponseInit, InvocationContext } from '@azure/functions';

export async function negotiate(request: HttpRequest, context: InvocationContext): Promise<HttpResponseInit> {

    return {
        status: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify(context.options.extraInputs, null, 2) 
    };    

};

const signalRInput = input.generic({
    type: 'signalRConnectionInfo',
    name: 'connectionInfo',
    hubName: 'default',
})

app.http('negotiate', {
    methods: ['POST', 'GET'],
    authLevel: 'anonymous',
    handler: negotiate,
    extraInputs: [signalRInput]
});
```

For the `output` binding:

```
/* 

V3 SYNTAX BEING CONVERTED TO V4 MODEL

{
  "type": "signalR",
  "name": "signalRMessages",
  "hubName": "default",
  "connectionStringSetting": "AzureSignalRConnectionString",
  "direction": "out"
}
 */
```

Inspiration from here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-table-output?tabs=isolated-process%2Cnodejs-v4%2Ctable-api&pivots=programming-language-typescript

I'm using the following code:

```
import { app, HttpRequest, output, HttpResponseInit, InvocationContext } from '@azure/functions';

export async function signalRNotify(request: HttpRequest, context: InvocationContext): Promise<HttpResponseInit> {


    const message = {
        target: 'newMessage',
        arguments: ['This is Aiden calling.']
    };

    context.extraOutputs.set(signalrOutput, message);
    return { status: 201 };

};

// This should provide the signalR upstream target to trigge
const signalrOutput = output.generic({
    type: 'signalR',
    name: 'signalRMessages',
    hubName: 'default',
    connectionStringSetting: "AzureSignalRConnectionString"
});


app.http('signalr-notify', {
    methods: ['POST', 'GET'],
    authLevel: 'anonymous',
    handler: signalRNotify,
    extraOutputs: [signalrOutput]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

have you been able to solve this issue? I was able to solve it by using some inspiration from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-signalr/signalr-concept-client-negotiation). As it state, the answer from the negotiate event should be one of three options, and as the Azure Function is just use to redirect the client to the actual hub, so I send back `{ url: <ENDPOINT>/client/?hub=<HUBNAME>, accessToken: <ACCESS-TOKEN> }`. The accessToken can be created using (from the same article in the section [Using ConnectionString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-signalr/signalr-concept-client-negotiation#using-connectionstring):

```
  let endpoint = /Endpoint=(.*?);/.exec(connectionString)[1];
  let accessKey = /AccessKey=(.*?);/.exec(connectionString)[1];
  let url = `${endpoint}/client/?hub=${hub}`;
  let token = jwt.sign({ aud: url }, accessKey, { expiresIn: 3600 });
  return ({ url: url, accessToken: token });
```

Comment: Hi Eliel, not yet.  Do you have a full example or Stackblitz showing your solution that you could share please?  That would be great.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delay, well my test function look like this https://github.com/eaquiler/signalr/blob/main/negotiate.ts

Comment: Hi Eliel, thanks for sending that through.  I've been on leave the past month but am starting to look at this again.  I'll update when I have something.  Cheers